# MVC Controller return Content instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model, controller

I've been working on a project were all of my requirements involved JSON. However now suddenly I have a need to return results from my model that can be used in an input elements value field. I can't use the solution I have been as I get objects returned instead of plain text for the value. This is the controller pattern I have been using:

```
public virtual JsonResult fooData()
{
    var fooresults = new fooQueries().fooTotal();
    return new JsonResult 
        { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = fooresults };
}
```

Is there a way to use return content instead of JsonResult? I'm fairly new to the .NET MVC framework and having some difficulty finding the correct way to do this.

My current results are formatted like this:

```
[{ "foo", 3 }]
```

Instead I would prefer to get plain text so that I can use an AJAX request to pass the 3 value into an input elements value="" field.

AJAX call I am using with the controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $('#fooValue').data('url'),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#fooValue').val(data);
    }
});
```

The data-url is equivalent to:

```
../fooController/fooData
```

I'm just using T4MVC.

Comment: Why can't you just set the input's value from the foo property of the deserialised json?

Comment: An example maybe? I'm in new territory with JSON. This sounds like a potentially better solution, but a reference or example would help. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you're using AJAX to invoke the controller action that returns the JSON? Are you using jQuery to perform the AJAX call?

Comment: I am using AJAX for that I'll add it above.

Answer (score 1):

Return a `ContentResult` instead of a `JsonResult`

```
public virtual ContentResult gooData()
{
    var fooresults = new fooQueries().fooTotal();
    return Content(fooresults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return content as:

```
return Content(fooresults);
```

But this wont be clean to you separate the elements as JSON return is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the shape of `fooresults` is, but you should be able to alter your AJAX call to the following:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: $('#fooValue').data('url'),
   success: function (data) {
    $('#fooValue').val(data.foo);
   }
});
```

If the dataType property of the jQuery ajax call isn't explictly set, then jQuery will try and infer the type of the return result based on the MIME type, which in your case will be JSON. Therefore jQuery will deserialise the JSON to a JSON object. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info.

Comment: I will give this a try. I'm guessing that somewhere in the JQuery API I can find how to use .serialize or such if I need to take it to a plain text type? Currently the output is a JSON object so it looks like value="[Object object]" and I would be able to change that? Thanks.

Comment: To serialise and deserialise JSON explictly, use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse respectively. They are supported natively on all modern browsers, but it's recommended to use the JSON-js library anyway (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as it will add support to older browsers if the functions aren't available.

Comment: This works "better" I guess. I changed it to be .val(data.PlainObject) however now I simply get value="" so it's good that I'm not getting [Object, object] however now nothing is being passed through. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why .PlainObject? it should be the name of the property on the type that you are returning from the action. In fact, it looks like you're returning a collection type (fooResults)? So how do you know which element in the collection's value to use?

Comment: There is only one "set" of results returned and it is formatted as such [{ "value", 4 }] and I'm just trying to get the 4 passed into value="". If the "value" part is included it's not a problem.

Comment: Sorry. I see the mistake you were talking about and corrected it. The result type is decimal? - with the question mark. All results I pass this way will be type decimal? unless I need to change that.

Comment: Ok, nullable types have two public properties - HasValue and Value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xkcd5cdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). HasValue is read only so isn't being serialised, so you're left with the 'value' property. So you can either use data.value on the client, or you can return result.Value on the server instead where result is your nullable decimal (after checking .HasValue you might want to provide a default value) and then use just 'data' on the client.

Comment: Interesting. It might take me a while to get this done. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

to return a Json, the method should be changed as follow:

```
public JsonResult fooData()
{
    var fooresults = new fooQueries().fooTotal();
    return  Json(fooresults , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```